# Issue on creating a Mist connection to a private blockchain (ethereum)

Tags: blockchain, ethereum

Good day!

I am trying to connect Mist to a private blockchain that I have created on ethereum. I have been following the below steps in the exact order to do so.

1. Initiating the genesis block with command :- `geth --datadir=./mychain/ init ./genesis.json`
2. Starting the blockchain with command :- `geth --datadir=./mychain`
3. Double click and open Mist when the above command fetches "IPC port opened".

To clarify :-

**mychain** is an empty folder where I want the blockchain data to be stored into.
I am doing all this in a **Windows** system.

The first command runs succesfully and says "Succesfully wrote genesis state". The second commands seems to stop and say "IPC endpoint opened" without any errors. 
But when I try and open Mist, it says cannot run ethereum as there is another node running.

**My findings on debugging**:- In the genesis block, I have mentioned the chainID as 1990 and the same is being called on my second command in the output. So I am sure the genesis block is initiated. However, when I checked the node.log file in the Mist folder, I noticed that Mist is looking for chainID = 1. Not sure if this is the problem, but I am unable to make Mist connect to my private net.

I would be grateful for any help on this matter.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Mist has it's own command line arguments to specify the data location, key store, etc. You'll need to add the `--rpc` option if you're starting `geth` yourself or use the `--node-datadir` option if you want to use Mist's embedded version.

> ```
> $ ./Mist.exe --help
>
> Usage: Mist.exe --help [Mist options] [Node options]
>
> Mist options:
>   --mode, -m              App UI mode: wallet, mist.  [string] [default: "mist"]
>   --node                  Node to use: geth, eth        [string] [default: null]
>   --network               Network to connect to: main, test
>                                                         [string] [default: null]
>   --rpc                   Path to node IPC socket file OR HTTP RPC hostport (if
>                           IPC socket file then --node-ipcpath will be set with
>                           this value).                                  [string]
>   --swarmurl              URL serving the Swarm HTTP API. If null, Mist will
>                           open a local node.
>                                      [string] [default: "http://localhost:8500"]
>   --gethpath              Path to Geth executable to use instead of default.
>                                                                         [string]
>   --ethpath               Path to Eth executable to use instead of default.
>                                                                         [string]
>   --ignore-gpu-blacklist  Ignores GPU blacklist (needed for some Linux
>                           installations).                              [boolean]
>   --reset-tabs            Reset Mist tabs to their default settings.   [boolean]
>   --logfile               Logs will be written to this file in addition to the
>                           console.                                      [string]
>   --loglevel              Minimum logging threshold: info, debug, error, trace
>                           (shows all logs, including possible passwords over
>                           IPC!).                      [string] [default: "info"]
>   --syncmode              Geth synchronization mode: [fast|light|full]  [string]
>   --version, -v           Display Mist version.                        [boolean]
>   --skiptimesynccheck     Disable checks for the presence of automatic time sync
>                           on your OS.                                  [boolean]
>
> Node options:
>   -  To pass options to the underlying node (e.g. Geth) use the --node- prefix,
>      e.g. --node-datadir
>
> Options:
>   -h, --help  Show help                                                [boolean]
> ```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion Adam. However, when I start geth from the command line it gets stuck at "IPC endpoint Opened". After this I am unable to use the command prompt to open mist. Could you please guide me with the right commands in order to get mist started on my private net.

Comment: Um....start another console to run Mist? Or run geth in the background?